# Multi-dimesional array initialisation in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

There's one pointer about the following code I can't figure out: the part in the function `set_array([][9])`, why the compiler gives allow this instead the normal full expression `set_array([4][9])`.However in the `main` part the `int array1[4][9]`, `array1[][9]` doesn't allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void set_array(int t_array[][9]);
int main(void) {
    int array1[4][9]; // array1[][9] doesn't allowed

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            array1[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
    set_array(array1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(*(array1 + i) + j));
            //printf("%d ", array1[i][j]);
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
void set_array(int t_array[][9]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            t_array[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }   
};
```

Any explanation about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because when you are doing two different things:

First you are declaring a variable named `array1`. In C, the compiler needs to know the amount of space you are declaring to reserve that memory amount to you. So you have to specify the complete size of your array:

`int array1[4][9];`

This way your compiler knows that you need `4 * 9` ints allocated.

Now, in your function the compiler does not need to know the size of your array (behind of scenes your array is converted to a pointer on your function calls), it needs only to know the size of its elements. So `t_array` is an pointer to elements of size `9 * sizeof(int)`. It is because of that you may declare your function the way you've declared:

`void set_array(int t_array[][9])`

But it is also possible to declare with all dimension sizes:

`void set_array(int t_array[4][9])`

But it doesn't matters to the compiler.

Comment: Now I can understand your answer, The layout of multi-dimensional array is liner, and when pass it to a functional only the pointer of the first element is passed, and with the type declaration, the function know how to apply the pointer arithmetic to it. so the first part can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

In function call array actually treated as pointer so in the function definition 
`t_array[][9]` is actually `(*t_array)[9] //pointer to array` 
but in the declaration of array you have to give size explicitly if declaring static array
so that compiler would allocate that much memory for the array.Hence, `array1[4][9]` is correct while `array1[][9]` is error.
But if you are doing `array1[][9]` , then you have to provide initializer list.

Comment: Could you tell me why the function invocation :` set_array(&array1[0]);` give me the partially changed array `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

1 1 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Comment: here array1 is having the address of whole array of 1st row(or column)depending upon implementation. (&array1[0])is same as (array1) of type (*)[n].But when you pass (&array) which of type (*)[m][n] and compiler will throw an error

Answer (score 2):

as comparison (C89):

when you write

```
int a[]
```

the compilre doesn't know how much memory needs to be allocated for 'a', in such a case the compiler needs to use the initialization to determine the size of the array:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3}; // sizeof(a)==sizeof(int)*3
```

when you only write

```
int a[][9];
```

the compiler doesn't know how large 'a' is so it cannot allocate adequate memory

in the case you have the array as an argument

```
void foo(int a[][9])
```

the function doesn't need to know how big both dimensions are because it is not allocating anything, it is just referencing 'a'. From the argument the function knows that it should treat 'a' as a multidimensional array (where the first dimension is an arbitrary number) when dereferencing it.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation, hitting right to the point, BTW could you tell me why I could invoke the method like this `set_array(&array1[0])`

Answer (score 1):

In C you have to give the array size a value when declaring it statically otherwise the compiler wont know how much memory to allocate to that variable.

When you pass the array as array[][9], it works because the compiler only needs to know the size the of the elements in the array, not how many elements it contains.  Therefore, passing array[][] as an argument will not work because the compiler doesn't know the size of the elements stored.

Comment: That's just the function prototype telling the compiler to expect an array to be passed to that function, which is different than actually declaring the variable.

Comment: When you pass an array, the compiler only needs to know that size of it's elements.  Not how many elements it has.

Comment: c standard says that in multidimentional array you have to give size of each dimensions except the first one

Comment: And that is because all multidimensions are mapped  to linear ram, so if sizes of further dimension are not known, compiler can't calculate further indexing

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and initialize without specifying the first dimension using an initialization list:

```
int array1[][9] = {
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
};
```

In C, if you initialize your array inline, you are only forced to specify dimentions sizes from the second on. They are necessary for the compiler to generate the code to index it, remember that multidimensional arrays (in C) are a continuos buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to arrays, you can only initialize them, so you'd have to do it all at once:

```
int array1[4][9] = {
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
};
```

Comment: I clear out the misleading comment part, thanks for your answer, but I  already know this. What I don't know is `array[][9]` in allowed